# optimized/minifed javascript code but still readable/maintainable

Tags: javascript, optimization, minify

I'm a beginner at javascript and learn a lot by looking already written code.

Some large javascript projects I've looked at have minified code and when expanding it it's not very readable.

almost all variables and functions are just defined by a letter looping trough the alphabet i.e a b c, aa, bb, cc and so on, also no commenting.

Out of curiosity is this a coding style or is there a tool that you use to optimize the code with?

seems hard to maintain such a project.

Comment: What you see is a minified version of the code. The biggest reason why we use such versions is to lower the traffic so websites can load faster.

Comment: Essentially we just use a tool to minify it so that: A: it loads a bit quicker, and B: it isn't as readable (meaning people have to go through more effort to copy/poke holes in the actual javascript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not a coding style (except if you're doing code-golfing manually for fun).

You take the unminified code and squeeze it through a tool such as https://github.com/terser/terser (which is probably the most popular at the time of writing).

You can see what Terser does online with their Try Terser tool. https://try.terser.org/

Comment: cool, make sense that there should be a tool for it, looked very masochistic writing it manually :D

Comment: Also worth noting (per the last line in the question), this is not something you do to *replace* the actual code so it won't affect the maintainability.